# Number of distinct non-empty subsequences of binary expansion

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, binary, subsequence, restricted-time

A subsequence is any sequence that you can get from another by deleting any amount of characters. The distinct non-empty subsequences of `100` are `0`, `1`, `00`, `10`, `100`. The distinct non-empty subsequences of `1010` are `0`, `1`, `00`, `01`, `10`, `11`, `010`, `100`, `101`, `110`, `1010`.

Write a program or function that given a positive integer *n* returns the number of distinct non-empty subsequences of the binary expansion of *n*.

Example: since `4` is `100` in binary, and we saw that it had five distinct non-empty subsequences above, so `f(4) = 5`. Starting from *n = 1*, the sequence begins:

```
1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 7, 10, 11, 9, 8, 9, 7, 4, 9, 14, 17, 15, 16, 19, 17, 12
```

However, your program must work for any *n < 2<sup>50</sup>* in under a second on any modern machine. Some large examples:

```
f(1099511627775) = 40
f(1099511627776) = 81
f(911188917558917) = 728765543
f(109260951837875) = 447464738
f(43765644099) = 5941674
```

Comment: I disagree with the time restriction.

Comment: This sounded really familiar, especially after looking at the plot. Turns out [I looked into a very closely related sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146194/50421) earlier this year, but I counted the number of distinct binary numbers, not binary strings, you get when taking subsequences (so I discounted leading zeros). I had even sandboxed it, but due to the equivalence in the Math.SE post, it would have been a dupe of some Stern-Brocot challenge. The plot of your sequence is a bit nicer (i.e. more chaotic) though. :)

Comment: @ATaco The time restriction has a good reason. There is an efficient algorithm, and it is interesting yet well golfable. If I don't have a time restriction I feel that nearly every answer would simply brute force all possible subsequences, which very, very quickly wouldn't work anymore. In a sense they're non-answers.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>95 bytes</s>  83 bytes

[-12 bytes thanks to Mr.XCoder :)]

```python
def f(x):
 v=[2,1];c=1
 for i in bin(x)[3:]:k=int(i);c+=v[k];v[1-k]+=v[k]
 return c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsMgEEX3nmKWkbaLaQhNlDmJuKmNdBAmQYykp7eVbj483uPvn/LeZGwnLYg4zws@pqlve60R4nBqo6CSu1/R20CoIG4ZGFjgyfLTbjTeJGIpA2sbLlRd8rY6vCX/BwV5LUcWCG3Pveuvun0B)

A note on the algorithm.
The algorithm computes the increment in unique subsequences given by the bit at a given position t.
The increment for the first bit is always 1. The algorithm then runs over the sequence of bits s(t) and adds the increment v[s(t)]. At each step, the increment for the complement of s(t), v[1 - s(t)] is updated to v[1]+v[0]. 
The final number is the sum of all increments.

It should run in O(log2(n)), where n is the input number.

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwEEX3OcUsE7SLqYgayUlCFm00OIuOIcRgT58q3Xx48N6P37zt3NXTTIg4jhMOfX9vXdYAQZ5KCyjGPlt0szcoIOwJCIjh84qSOLdv4kuznXZK@8YUS24uFh/k/iAgrflIDL7GdAXyflX1Bw) or [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsMgEEX3nmKWkbaLaQhNlDmJuKmNdBAmQYykp7eVbj483uPvn/LeZGwnLYg4zws@pqlve60R4nBqo6CSu1/R20CoIG4ZGFjgyfLTbjTeJGIpA2sbLlRd8rY6vCX/BwV5LUcWCG3Pveuvun0B)

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```js
f=(n,r=~(a=[]))=>n<1?~r:f(n/2,r*2-~~a[n&=1],a[n]=r)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,r=~(a=[]))=>n<1?~r:f(n/2,r*2-~~a[n&=1],a[n]=r)

console.log(f(1099511627775))   // 40
console.log(f(1099511627776))   // 81
console.log(f(911188917558917)) // 728765543
console.log(f(109260951837875)) // 447464738
console.log(f(43765644099))     // 5941674
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
f = (                      // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                       //   n = integer
  r = ~(                   //   r = last result, initially set to -1
    a = []                 //   and using a[] = last results for 0 and 1,
  )                        //   implicitly initialized to [0, 0]
) =>                       //
  n < 1 ?                  // if n is less than 1:
    ~r                     //   we're done: return -(r + 1)
  :                        // else:
    f(                     //   do a recursive call with:
      n / 2,               //     n / 2
      r * 2 - ~~a[n &= 1], //     updated result = r * 2 - last result for this binary digit
      a[n] = r             //     update last result for this binary digit
    )                      //   end of recursive call
```

## Non-recursive version, 63 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ThePirateBay*

```js
s=>[...s.toString(2)].map(l=c=>l[p=r,r=r*2-~~l[c],c]=p,r=1)|r-1
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>[...s.toString(2)].map(l=c=>l[p=r,r=r*2-~~l[c],c]=p,r=1)|r-1

console.log(f(1099511627775))   // 40
console.log(f(1099511627776))   // 81
console.log(f(911188917558917)) // 728765543
console.log(f(109260951837875)) // 447464738
console.log(f(43765644099))     // 5941674
```

Comment: I think you can save 3 bytes by assigning the inner function (the first argument of `map`) to the flag variable `l` instead of an empty array.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Nice one. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,a=1,b=1:x and f(x/2,a+~x%2*b,x%2*a+b)or a+b-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxLDsIwDAXX9BTeIMU0iNqo9CPlMI5KoBJNq6gLs@HqIbCZN5s323t/rpFzDu4li58E1Ioj6x2NChInCEYvbKX@6JFP3v4otcc1QZkz51BMYY6QJD7uhiwTjtVhS3PcTTkjVn8vIWoGvjVDS/2167sW8xc)

Taking the [method from NofP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145397/20260).

**59 bytes iteratively:**

```python
x=input()
v=[1,1]
while x:v[x%2]=sum(v);x/=2
print sum(v)-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M6@gtERDk6vMNtpQxzCWqzwjMydVocKqLLpC1SjWtrg0V6NM07pC39aIq6AoM69EASKiC9RsaWhoaGFhaWhuagoiAQ)

Comment: nice algorithm.  would you mind adding just a short explanation about why it works?

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
B3;BSṛ¦/’S
```

This uses [@xnor's improvement](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145398/12012) on [@NofP's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145397/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/J2Nop@OHO2YeW6T9qmBn8/@iew@2Pmta4//9vaGBpaWpoaGZkbm5uqqOAzDXTUbA0NDS0sLA0NDc1BZFgeSMzA6ASC2NzC5AGE2NzM1MzExOgPgA)

#### Background

Let **(a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>)** be a finite binary sequence. For each non-negative integer **k ≤ n**, define **o<sub>k</sub>** as the number of unique subsequences of **(a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>k</sub>)** that are either empty or end in **1**, **z<sub>k</sub>** as the number of unique subsequences that are either empty or end in **0**.

Clearly, **o<sub>0</sub> = z<sub>0</sub> = 1**, as the only subsequence of the empty sequence is the empty sequence.

For each index **k**, the total number of subsequences of **(a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>k</sub>)** is **o<sub>k</sub> + z<sub>k</sub> - 1** (subtracting **1** accounts for the fact that both **o<sub>k</sub>** and **z<sub>k</sub>** count the empty sequence). The total number of *non-empty* subsequences is therefore **o<sub>k</sub> + z<sub>k</sub> - 2**. The challenge asks to compute **o<sub>n</sub> + z<sub>n</sub> - 2**.

Whenever **k > 0**, we can compute **o<sub>k</sub>** and **z<sub>k</sub>** recursively. There are two cases:

- #### a<sub>k</sub> = 1

  **z<sub>k</sub> = z<sub>k-1</sub>**, since **(a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>k-1</sub>)** and **(a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>k-1</sub>, 1)** have the same subsequences that end in **0**.

  For each of the **o<sub>k</sub> - 1** non-empty subsequences of **(a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>k</sub>)** that end in **1**, we can remove the trailing **1** to obtain one of the **o<sub>k-1</sub> + z<sub>k-1</sub> - 1** subsequences **(a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>k-1</sub>)**. Conversely, appending a **1** to each of the latter **o<sub>k-1</sub> + z<sub>k-1</sub> - 1** sequences results in one of the **o<sub>k</sub> - 1** former sequences. Thus, **o<sub>k</sub> - 1 = o<sub>k-1</sub> + z<sub>k-1</sub> - 1** and **o<sub>k</sub> = o<sub>k-1</sub> + z<sub>k-1</sub>**.
- #### a<sub>k</sub> = 0

  Similarly to the previous case, we obtain the recursive formulae **o<sub>k</sub> = o<sub>k-1</sub>** and **z<sub>k</sub> = z<sub>k-1</sub> + o<sub>k-1</sub>**.

#### How it works

```
B3;BSṛ¦/’S  Main link. Argument: n (positive integer)

B           Binary; convert n to base 2.
 3;         Prepend a 3.
   B        Binary; convert all integers in the resulting array to base 2, mapping
            0 to [0], 1 to [1], and the prepended 3 to [1, 1].
       /    Reduce the resulting array by the quicklink to the left, which will be 
            called with left argument [x, y] (integer pair) and right argument [j] 
            (either [0] or [1]).
      ¦     Sparse application.
    S           Compute the sum (x + y) and...
     ṛ          for each index in the right argument (i.e., for j)...
            replace the element of [x, y] at that index with (x + y).
       ’    Decrement both integers in the resulting pair.
        S   Take the sum.
```

Comment: hey dennis, would you mind adding a short explanation about why the algorithm works?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
0¸sbvDO>yǝ}O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f4NCO4qQyF3@7yuNza/3//7c0NDS0sLA0NDc1BZEA) Explanation: As pointed out by the other answers, the number of subsequences for a binary string `a..y0` that end in a 1 is the same as the number for the binary string `a..y`, while the number that end in a `0` is the total number of subsequences for the binary string `a..y` (which each gain a `0` suffix) plus one for `0` itself. Unlike the other answers I don't include the empty subsequence as this saves a byte constructing the initial state.

```
0¸s             Push [0] under the input
   b            Convert the input to binary
    v     }     Loop over the digits
     D          Duplicate the array
      O         Take the sum
       >        Increment
        yǝ      Replace the index corresponding to the binary digit
           O    Take the sum of the final array
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 97 bytes

```java
n->f(n,1,1)long f(long n,long a,long b){return n>0?f(n/2,a+Math.floorMod(~n,2)*b,n%2*a+b):a+b-2;}
```

Port of [*@xnor*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145398/52210), which in turn is an improvement of [*@NofP*'s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145397/52210).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lU9Nc4IwFLzzK96lM4kCGpSvUu0fUC8eOz0EDIqFFwaCHcehf50G8NhO7WV3Xt5m3@6ZX7glS4Hnw0eX5LyuYcszvBkAGSpRpTwRsOtHgFziERKy6QlppN9aQ8MOEFbQobVOCZrMZNSItHo2g51UUPJKgUxBnQTEVyWsRDaojMErJQOhORAfKaa3SqimQsD1/FVbzhyTT7dcnew0l7LaygP5QtOhk9jEJ2fCpzF91mA5UdsBlE2cZwnUiitNF5kdoNCFyF5VGR7f3oHTsU1fEwqdHMXnMJChEkAqqzFXtmKbCLKXleP2PJ3SYQ@wv9ZKFLZslF1qV5UjKWy0E5LRu8cPit834182D0OXMc/xfd/d0P/Ivb/lIWMsCELmu26PD/k73lyfCBZ@8Eig5cL3XG@51Lnu4tZou28)

---

Maybe it's a good thing the [restricted-time](/questions/tagged/restricted-time)-tag was present, because I initially had the following to bruteforce all subsequences:

```java
import java.util.*;n->p(n.toString(n,2)).size()-1;Set p(String s){Set r=new HashSet();r.add("");if(s.isEmpty())return r;Set q=p(s.substring(1));r.addAll(q);for(Object o:q)r.add(""+s.charAt(0)+o);return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lVJLb@IwEL7zK0a9rA3FEEoIbJaVeqi0BworsbfVHpzEgGliB3vSiq347ew40FsrdS8ez@Obxzezl8@yb2tl9sXTWVe1dQh7sokGdSm6KQAMBvBTktluAHcKsiOqfm4bg51OXkrv4VFq89oB0AaV28hcwTKoAKU1W8jZIgjDU7KdOvQswcAczqb/vWZGoF2j02bLzO2Ic@H1X8V4P@pcSy8tQv1@@bUiF7ugwfPXoLu5US/wQ/odaYynTsiiYDc3PNUb5oX2D1WNR8a5U9g4Ay4NqMO8JqdvMn9pJeJX5H1ZsgNPN9axVbZXObXx9cDfkva8yHfS3SMb8p4lyFvO0xmgbrJS5@BRIolnqwuoiKhrv7//gOQXlgJ9UBEjofOgsJYqgFC1pVDPo0UK@tt8FAfZ6/HWD7A@elSVsA2KmrJiaVgljMiZ5tcc70R87Llgo@FsFkfRZJQkSbzg/xM@acPbeFrdr532kLmGFkaj0Fl4W9JZWeOhsMqbLwgv1j2FOdvV0jEhfZxSgIq@ufTK30LRkG5h1eBq86gq644PzhGkhVlLMLdVQGv0QlxKdz9sdhZF0XQ6i5I4Du@nphtNhjTg9C6ZfoaO8V0yiSfjMbESgruD9upP538)

Which also worked, but took way too long for the last three test cases. Not to mention it's way longer (**<s>208</s> 204 bytes**).

Answer (score 1):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 321 bytes

```
00 C0 20 FD AE A2 00 9D 4F C1 E8 20 73 00 90 F7 9D 4F C1 A0 FF C8 B9 4F C1 D0
FA A2 15 CA 88 30 0A B9 4F C1 29 0F 9D 4F C1 10 F2 A9 00 9D 4F C1 CA 10 F8 A9
00 A0 07 99 64 C1 88 10 FA A0 40 A2 6C 18 BD E4 C0 90 02 09 10 4A 9D E4 C0 E8
10 F2 A2 07 7E 64 C1 CA 10 FA 88 F0 13 A2 13 BD 50 C1 C9 08 30 05 E9 03 9D 50
C1 CA 10 F1 30 D1 A2 0F A9 00 9D 3F C1 CA D0 FA A9 01 8D 3F C1 8D 47 C1 A2 08
CA BD 64 C1 F0 FA A0 09 1E 64 C1 88 90 FA B0 0A CA 30 28 A0 08 1E 64 C1 90 04
A9 47 B0 02 A9 4F 8D AF C0 86 FE A2 F8 18 BD 47 C0 7D 4F C0 9D 47 C0 E8 D0 F4
A6 FE 88 D0 DC F0 D5 A2 F8 BD 47 C0 7D 4F C0 9D 6C C0 E8 D0 F4 AD 64 C1 E9 01
8D 64 C1 A2 F9 BD 6C C0 E9 00 9D 6C C0 E8 D0 F5 A0 15 A9 00 99 4E C1 88 D0 FA
A0 40 A2 13 BD 50 C1 C9 05 30 05 69 02 9D 50 C1 CA 10 F1 0E 64 C1 A2 F9 3E 6C
C0 E8 D0 FA A2 13 BD 50 C1 2A C9 10 29 0F 9D 50 C1 CA 10 F2 88 D0 D1 E0 14 F0
06 E8 BD 4F C1 F0 F6 09 30 99 4F C1 C8 E8 E0 15 F0 05 BD 4F C1 90 F0 A9 00 99
4F C1 A9 4F A0 C1 4C 1E AB
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22binseq.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMAg/a6iAJ1PweggcwCQ951PwaD/yLlPwdD6ohXKiDAKuU/BKQ+dT8EQ8qkAnU/ByhD4qQCgB5lkwYgQ+qBAomwYveTAkAIJEEqd5MDoEPKiB35kwcoQ+ojwE6ITvVDByQgwBekDnVDByhDxMNGiD6kAnT/BytD6qQGNP8GNR8GiCMq9ZMHw+qAJHmTBiJD6sArKMCigCB5kwZAEqUewAqlPja/Ahv6i+Bi9R8B9T8CdR8Do0PSm/ojQ3PDVovi9R8B9T8CdbMDo0PStZMHpAY1kwaL5vWzA6QCdbMDo0PWgFakAmU7BiND6oECiE71QwckFMAVpAp1QwcoQ8Q5kwaL5PmzA6ND6ohO9UMEqyRApD51QwcoQ8ojQ0eAU8AbovU/B8PYJMJlPwcjo4BXwBb1PwZDwqQCZT8GpT6DBTB6r%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22binseq.prg%22%7D%7D)**

**[Online demo with error checking](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22binseq.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMAghcCiD6kAnVjBytD6qQGNWMGNYMGiCMq9fcHw+qAJHn3BiJD6sArKMCigCB59wZAEqWCwAqlojUbAhv6i+Bi9YMB9aMCdYMDo0PSm/ojQ3PDVovi9YMB9aMCdhcDo0PStfcHpAY19waL5vYXA6QCdhcDo0PUg/cCpaKDBTB6rTAivTEiyIP2usPWiAJ1owejgFfDuIHMAkPOdaMGg/8i5aMHQ+qIVyogwCrlowSkPnWjBEPKpAJ1owcoQ+KkAoAeZfcGIEPqgQKJsGL39wJACCRBKnf3A6BDyogd+fcHKEPqI0AasfMHQmWCiE71pwckIMAXpA51pwcoQ8TDLoBWpAJlnwYjQ+qBAohO9acHJBTAFaQKdacHKEPEOfcGi+T6FwOjQ+qITvWnBKskQKQ+dacHKEPKI0NHgFPAG6L1owfD2CTCZaMHI6OAV8AW9aMGQ8KkAmWjBYA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22binseq.prg%22%7D%7D)** (346 bytes)

**Usage:** `sys49152,[n]`, e.g. `sys49152,911188917558917`.

The time restriction and the test-cases require solutions to calculate in 64bit numbers, so time to prove the C64 qualifies as "**modern machine**" ;)

Of course, this needs quite a bit of code, the OS doesn't provide **anything** for integers wider than 16bit. The lame part here: it's *yet another implementation* (slightly modified) of [NofP's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145397/71420) resp. [xnor's improved variant](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145398/71420). Thanks for the idea ;)

---

#### Explanation

Here's a commented disassembly listing of the relevant part doing the algorithm:

```
.C:c06c  A2 0F       LDX #$0F           ; 15 bytes to clear
.C:c06e  A9 00       LDA #$00
.C:c070   .clearloop:
.C:c070  9D 3F C1    STA .num_a,X
.C:c073  CA          DEX
.C:c074  D0 FA       BNE .clearloop
.C:c076  A9 01       LDA #$01           ; initialize num_a and num_b
.C:c078  8D 3F C1    STA .num_a         ; to 1
.C:c07b  8D 47 C1    STA .num_b
.C:c07e  A2 08       LDX #$08           ; 8 bytes of input to check,
.C:c080   .findmsb:                     ; start at most significant
.C:c080  CA          DEX
.C:c081  BD 64 C1    LDA .nc_num,X
.C:c084  F0 FA       BEQ .findmsb       ; repeat until non-0 byte found
.C:c086  A0 09       LDY #$09           ; 8 bits to check (+1 for pre dec)
.C:c088   .findbit:
.C:c088  1E 64 C1    ASL .nc_num,X      ; shift left, highest bit to carry
.C:c08b  88          DEY
.C:c08c  90 FA       BCC .findbit       ; bit was zero -> repeat
.C:c08e  B0 0A       BCS .loopentry     ; jump into calculation loop
.C:c090   .mainloop:
.C:c090  CA          DEX                ; next byte
.C:c091  30 28       BMI .done          ; index -1? -> done calculating
.C:c093  A0 08       LDY #$08           ; 8 bits to check
.C:c095   .bitloop:
.C:c095  1E 64 C1    ASL .nc_num,X      ; shift left, highest bit to carry
.C:c098  90 04       BCC .tgt_b         ; if 0, store addition result in num_b
.C:c09a   .loopentry:
.C:c09a  A9 47       LDA #$47
.C:c09c  B0 02       BCS .tgt_a         ; ... else store in num_a ...
.C:c09e   .tgt_b:
.C:c09e  A9 4F       LDA #$4F
.C:c0a0   .tgt_a:
.C:c0a0  8D AF C0    STA $C0AF          ; ... using self-modification.
.C:c0a3  86 FE       STX $FE            ; save byte index
.C:c0a5  A2 F8       LDX #$F8           ; index for adding
.C:c0a7  18          CLC
.C:c0a8   .addloop:
.C:c0a8  BD 47 C0    LDA $C047,X        ; load byte from num_a
.C:c0ab  7D 4F C0    ADC $C04F,X        ; add byte from num_b
.C:c0ae  9D 47 C0    STA $C047,X        ; store to num_a or num_b
.C:c0b1  E8          INX                ; next index
.C:c0b2  D0 F4       BNE .addloop       ; done if index overflown
.C:c0b4  A6 FE       LDX $FE            ; restore byte index
.C:c0b6  88          DEY                ; decrement bit index
.C:c0b7  D0 DC       BNE .bitloop       ; bits left in current byte -> repeat
.C:c0b9  F0 D5       BEQ .mainloop      ; else repeat main loop
.C:c0bb   .done:
.C:c0bb  A2 F8       LDX #$F8           ; index for adding
.C:c0bd   .addloop2:
.C:c0bd  BD 47 C0    LDA $C047,X        ; load byte from num_a
.C:c0c0  7D 4F C0    ADC $C04F,X        ; add byte from num_b
.C:c0c3  9D 6C C0    STA $C06C,X        ; store to nc_num (result)
.C:c0c6  E8          INX                ; next index
.C:c0c7  D0 F4       BNE .addloop2      ; done if index overflown
.C:c0c9  AD 64 C1    LDA .nc_num        ; load least significant result byte
.C:c0cc  E9 01       SBC #$01           ; subtract 2 (1 + negated carry)
.C:c0ce  8D 64 C1    STA .nc_num        ; store least significant result byte
.C:c0d1  A2 F9       LDX #$F9           ; index for subtract
.C:c0d3   .subloop:
.C:c0d3  BD 6C C0    LDA $C06C,X        ; subtract 0 from all other bytes
.C:c0d6  E9 00       SBC #$00           ; for handling carry if necessary
.C:c0d8  9D 6C C0    STA $C06C,X
.C:c0db  E8          INX
.C:c0dc  D0 F5       BNE .subloop
```

The rest is input/output and converting between string and 64bit unsigned integer (little-endian) using some double-dabble algorithm. In case you're interested, [here's the whole assembly source for the version with error-checking](https://github.com/Zirias/c64binseq) -- the "golfed" version is in the branch "golf".